# Executing any type of SQL query by writing it in ASP.net multiline textbox

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, sql-server, ado.net

I want to create a ASP.NET page which contains a multi-line textbox. Whatever query i will write in it for my db , the query should get executed.

Like if I want to update a stored procedure then also i should be able to do that.
How to achieve this?

Comment: This site is really for questions, not having people do your work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you know about security issues. Use standard `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` classes.

```
using(var cnn = new SqlConnection("-my-connection-string-")){
    using(var cmd = cnn.CreateCommand()) {
        cmd.CommandText = this.txtSqlCommand.Text;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I update Stored Procedure online through this textbox[txtSqlCommand]

Comment: You can do it with standard T-SQL script. Look for "ALTER PROCEDURE".

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to use a SqlDataReader() to enumerate the results. For instance, if you wanted to fire a SQL Query that returned results you would need to add the following:

```
using(var cn = new SqlConnection("-my-connection-string-"))
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cn, this.txtSqlCommand.Text);  
    using(SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
          while(dr.Read())
          {
                 ...
          }
    }
}
```

I've done exactly the same thing on a website I built, so I can help you with that if you like. Also, when you have long running queries, you might want to consider the fact that the browser / ASP.net may timeout, so you would need to build an AJAX based polling mechanism.